# Fetch URLSearchparams with 2 params not working

Tags: javascript, fetch

## Why is this not working

`fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/calender/"+new URLSearchParams(4)+"/"+  new URLSearchParams("2023- 02-02"))`

[image]

i tried it with Postman, where its working

Comment: [not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem. Please read [ask].

Comment: `4` and `"2023- 02-02"` are nonsense values to pass to `URLSearchParams`, and it doesn't make sense to strinfigy `URLSearchParams` into the *middle* of a URL path so I haven't a clue what you expect this to do.

Comment: Is it possible to add a Body where i can use an Array or Object for the Get method from Fetch

Comment: GET requests can't have bodies.